# Build size different for minimum deployment target support in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, build, cocoapods

I have create Archive build for minimum target iOS 11 and size is around 190 MB

Same build i set for minimum deployment target of iOS 13.2 and size is around 35 MB

Here is list of Pods which i am using,

```
  pod 'Alamofire', '~> 5.2'
  pod 'Kingfisher', '~> 5.0'
  pod 'lottie-ios'
  pod 'SwiftLint'
  pod 'Hero'
  pod 'SwiftyBeaver'
  pod 'SnapKit', '~> 5.0.0'
  pod 'BRYXBanner'
  pod 'DropDown'
  pod 'IQKeyboardManager'
```

- And there are not more than 2 MB resources in bundle.

What's cause of too much different in size?

Answer (score 1):

This is because of the 2 reasons:

1. `Assets.car` file is compiled version of the assets catalog which is generated in the .ipa package, this optimised in iOS 13 so it reduced the size immensely.
2. The exported Frameworks in the .ipa package now export only `Unix Executable` file and do not include `.dylib files` of the frameworks. It reduce huge amount of size for some the pods.

So, no worries with the reduction in size. Have fun!

Comment: Ok, how to decrease size in iOS 11 as well?

Comment: Other than this reduction in size, you have to adopt optimisation techniques. Following developer documentation will help you quickly sort out size issues: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/reducing_your_app_s_size/doing_basic_optimization_to_reduce_your_app_s_size